# FOREACH with collection in cypher

Tags: foreach, neo4j, cypher

I have a collection of rels,created using this

```
MATCH (u:user)-[i:INTEREST]->(t:term)
WITH COLLECT([i,t]) AS its
RETURN its
```

and it returns the array of rels and nodes correctly.
see also http://console.neo4j.org/r/cw7saq

Now I want to set the properties of the relationship, but don't see how I can access the rels in the array. Tried this,

```
MATCH (u:user)-[i:INTEREST]->(t:term)
WITH COLLECT([i,t]) AS its
FOREACH (it IN its |
         SET it[0].testprop=89292" )
```

but it returns an error

```
Error: Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map, a relationship pattern, '(', '.' or '=' (line 4, column 16)
"         SET it[0].testprop=89292" )"
```

anyone knows what is the right syntax to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyone encountering a subset error like mentioned by OP can resolve it with parentheses:

```
MATCH (u:user)-[i:INTEREST]->(t:term)
WITH COLLECT([i,t]) AS its
FOREACH (it IN its |
     SET (it[0]).testprop=89292" )
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to collect the term nodes as well. Just do it as follows:

```
MATCH path=(u:user)-[i:INTEREST]->(t:term)
FOREACH (n IN rels(path) | set n.testprop=89292)
```

Comment: Thanks @tstorms. Accepting your answer since it is correct in the given context. However the real reason why I'm collecting the term nodes as well is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482138/combining-foreach-and-case-to-set-remove-relation-properties

Comment: Thanks, I've answered the other question as well. Feel free to upvote. ;-)