# combining foreach and case to set/remove relation properties

Tags: foreach, neo4j, case, cypher

I have two collections, one containing nodes, and another containing rels and nodes (see http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ijoqaa)

What I try to achieve is to update the rel properties , depending on the whether a node in one collection is also present in the other. The code below illustrates this  (hopefully), although it's not valid cypher.

```
FOREACH (iterm in iterms|
    CASE
        WHEN NOT (iterm[1] IN iaterms) THEN
            REMOVE iterms[0].pos,iterms[0].neg
            SET iterm[0].explicit=1
    END
)
```

Question: what is the way to do this in cypher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
MATCH (u:user)-[i:INTEREST]->(t)
WHERE NOT u-[:RELEVANCE]->()-[:ISABOUT]->t
REMOVE i.neg, i.pos
SET i.explicit = 1
```

Comment: solution seems to work. The one in the other answer too. Will try against larger dataset, to see which one to accept. thanks to both of you.

Comment: ok guys. Although unexpected, I see hardly any difference in terms of performance , even with a dataset with a 10k docs, 12k terms and a total of 1M [:ISABOUT] rels. I will accept @jjaderberg 's answer , because it's shorter and uses a single match. I know it's arbitrary but I hope you can both live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you have at the console, I think your query could be quite simple. There's no need to iterate with a `foreach` construction.

```
MATCH (u:user)-[r:RELEVANCE]->()-[ia:ISABOUT]->(t:term)
WITH u, collect(t) AS terms
MATCH (u)-[i:INTEREST]->(t2:term)
WHERE NONE(t IN terms WHERE t = t2)
REMOVE i.pos, i.neg
SET i.explicit = 1
```

Comment: thanks @tstorms. I'm afraid that your answer is not correct, since it does not update the correct rels. After running your cypher, you get this http://console.neo4j.org/?id=es9hti while it should be the "Television" relation that is updated. Also, the performace will be an issue, since we have a couple of 100k docs with each up to 100 [:ISABOUT] rels. From what I see, the collection route is considerably faster.

Comment: Hope I fully understand your question now. I've updated the query @Ophileon.

Comment: solution seems to work. The one in the other answer too. Will try against larger dataset, to see which one to accept. thanks to both of you.

Comment: ok guys. Although unexpected, I see hardly any difference in terms of performance , even with a dataset with a 10k docs, 12k terms and a total of 1M [:ISABOUT] rels. I will accept @jjaderberg 's answer , because it's shorter and uses a single match. I know it's arbitrary but I hope you can both live with it.